# Sass variable undefined during Rails asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I have several dozen sub directories in my stylesheets folder, many of which refer to each other with variables defined in the file `_settings.sass`. In my `application.sass` file, I importing settings first:

```
@import "settings"
@import "folder-one/some-sass-file"
@import "folder-two/some-other-sass-file"
```

This works well in development, but when I try to precompile, I get an error about `$namespace` being undefined in "folder-one/some-sass-file"--even though it's defined right there at the top in `_settings.sass`.

This seems to be happening because the compiler is trying to compile everything in sequential order, rather than looking at `application.sass`. Am I understanding this right? And if so, what can I do to remedy the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add @import "settings" into your some-sass-file. Asset pipeline will minify it for you so there is no problem.